# What's the case of float division returning inf and finite value?

Tags: c, division, inf

I have written this snippet of code and I cannot understand why this float division returns `inf` when `args[2] = 200` and `5.0` when `args[2] = 2000`. Is this caused because I am exceeding some decimal position boundary?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int nargs, char **args) {

    float t = atoi(args[1]);   
    float dt = atoi(args[2])/1000;

    float nsamples = (t/dt);
    printf("%f\n", nsamples);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What's the input?

Comment: let's say 10 and 200 or 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just getting tripped up by integer division (200 / 1000 = 0).

Change `float dt = atoi(args[2])/1000;` -> `float dt = atoi(args[2])/1000.0f;`

Comment: silly mistake. thanks a lot. it worked.

Comment: do I need that f at the end of the line? if so, what for?

Comment: `1000.0` is a double, `1000.0f` is a float. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal

Comment: @GiannisGonidelis 1000.0 is also fine

Comment: @Ayxan: `1000.0f` and `1000.0` are equal, but this is not true for floating-point constants in general. Programmers should be aware of the difference in types and values that result—please do not recommend that people use casually `double` constants with `float` operations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil your point is valid, but programmers should generally prefer  `double` over `float` anyway.